# Python Iterator Protocol __iter__ in iterator return value?

Tags: python, iterator, iterable

So I recently learned about the iterator protocol in my python class and I was told the `__iter__(self)` method should always return a new iterator instead of `self`. In the Fluent Python book, it talks about returning `self` inside the iterator so I'm not sure why my instructor told me I can't use self for the return value.

Here's the example that we had in our exam and I lost marks for using self instead of FileNamesIterator.

```
class FileNamesIterator:
    """
    Iterator that iterates over all the file names in the
    FileNamesIterable.
    """

    def __init__(self, filename_iterable: FileNamesIterable):
        self.filename_iterable = filename_iterable
        self.curr_index = 0

    def __next__(self) -> str:
        file_list = self.filename_iterable.file_list
        if self.curr_index == len(file_list):
            raise StopIteration()

        next_file_name = file_list[self.curr_index]
        self.curr_index += 1

        if ".png" in next_file_name:
            next_file_name = f"{next_file_name} - Portable Network Graphics " \
                             f"File"
        elif ".gif" in next_file_name:
            next_file_name = f"{next_file_name} - Graphics Interchange " \
                             f"Format File"

        return next_file_name

    def __iter__(self) -> FileNamesIterator:
        return self


class FileNamesIterable:
    def __init__(self, file_list: list):
        self.file_list = file_list

    def __iter__(self) -> FileNamesIterator:
        return FileNamesIterator(self)
```

Answer (score 0):

To implement the iterator protocol in a container class you add an `__iter__` method to it. This allows iteration of class instances with `for` loop because it calls `iter()` over the class instance to get an iterator object (from `instance.__iter__()`, and then calls the `__next__` method from the returned object (the iterator) until it gets exhausted (raising `StopIteration` instead of returning yet another data value). This is why the `__iter__`method of the iterator class should return an object with a `__next__` method.

If the class that implements the protocol can have the `__next__` method itself you can just return `self` from `__iter__`:

```
class MyIterator:
    def __init__(self, data):
        self._data = data
        self._index = 0

    def __next__(self):
        if self._index == len(self._data):
            raise StopIteration
        self._index += 1
        return self._data[self._index-1]

    def __iter__(self):
        return self
```

If you separate the iterator class from the iterable object you have to return a new iterator object, not `self` (nor the iterator class name):

```
class Iterator:
    def __init__(self, iterable):
        self._iterable = iterable

    # required for the iterator protocol
    def __next__(self):
        if not self._iterable:
            raise StopIteration
        value = self._iterable.pop(0)
        return value

    # required for the iterator protocol. It *has* to return self
    def __iter__(self):
        return self


class Container(list):
    """
    This container is a list. A list is already an iterable
    but we override the list __iter__ just to see how its code
    should be like
    """
    def __iter__(self):
        """
        Returns an iterator protocol compliant object. Note it is an
        instance, not the Iterator class. Otherwise it raises TypeError
        (no iterator type. Note also that it is a *new* iterator instance.
        """
        return Iterator(self)


print("Using a single class:")
it = MyIterator([1, 2, 3])
print(it)

for elem in it:
    print(elem)

print()

print("Separating the iterator class from the container class:")
container = Container((1, 2, 3))
it = iter(container)
print(it)

print(next(it))
print(next(it))
print(next(it))

print()

for elem in container:
    print(elem)
```

Output:

```
Using a single class:
<__main__.MyIterator object at 0x7f65a23b6fd0>
1
2
3

Separating the iterator class from the container class:
<__main__.Iterator object at 0x7f65a23b6ca0>
1
2
3
```